# Output of the for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop

```
int main() {
    int i,j,count;
    count=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++);
    { 
        for(j=0;j<5;j++);
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

here if we put ; after for() then for loop doesn't run anything. Then how does count becomes 1 after execution of the program?

Comment: considering that putting `;` right after `for` would be close to a no-op, your block will be executed once, beside the error in your syntax, what is your question ?

Comment: This something you can easily work out for yourself by stepping through the code with a debugger.

Comment: What did you expect `count` to become if not `1`?

Answer (score 6):

There is one occurrence of

```
 count++;
```

in the program which increments the counter only once.

To explain:

```
int main() {
      int i,j,count;
      count=0;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++);  
     {                       // i == 5, count == 0
        for(j=0;j<5;j++);    
            {                // i == 5, j == 5, count == 0
                count++;     // i == 5, j == 5, count == 1
            }
      }
      printf("%d",count);     //i == 5, j == 5, count == 1
      return 0;
     }
```

That said, as you mentioned

> here if we put `;` after for() then for loop doesn't run anything.

is not entirely true. If you put the `;` after the loop construct, it behaves as if the loop body is empty, i.e., there is no code in the loop body. The loop still runs, and the next block is not considered as the loop body, rather part of the unconditional flow.

Don't be fooled just by the indentation. Your code, can be re-written as

```
int main(void) {
      int i,j,count;
      count=0;
      for(i=0; i<5; i++)   // ; removed
      {
         // no code
      }
      {                         // just another block, not previous loop body 
      for(j=0;j<5;j++)    // ; removed
      {
         // again no code
      }
      {                         // again just another block, not previous loop body 
          count++;
      }
      }
      printf("%d",count);
      return 0;
     }
```

Which basically boils down to:

```
int main() {
      int count = 0;

      {
         count++;
      }

      printf("%d",count);
      return 0;
     }
```

Comment: please explain, what are the line with `for` are really doing, I think @padmaR seems to miss this mistake

Comment: @dvhh I thought the comments are self-explanatory, but I'll add a couple of lines.

Answer (score 2):

I think your confusion might be about putting the `;` after the `for` statment.

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
```

is the same as writing

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
;
}
```

C looks at the first statement after the `for (...)` (in this case that is the `;` statement), and then executes that as the body of the for-loop. So, when you write

```
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++);
{
 // other stuff
}
```

Your program basically skips the for-loop, since it does `;` 5 times. Then, the `//other stuff` gets executed once, since it's not a part of the for-loop. Does this make sense?

Therefore, your code only increments `count` once.

Answer (score 1):

Once you ignore the `for` loops, the rest becomes:

```
int main() {
    int i,j,count;
    count=0;
    { 
        {
            count++;
        }
    }
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

So you may see the `counter` is getting incremented once.

Comment: please explain why the `for` loop could be ignored, as @PadmaR might not be aware of why

Comment: @dvhh i'm confident in him =)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is look like below,after putting an ; at the end of both for loop.

```
int main() {
    int i,j,count;
    count=0;
    for(i=0; i<5; i++);
    {
          //do nothing
    }
    for(j=0;j<5;j++);
    {
         //do nothing
    }
    count++;
    printf("%d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

both for loop do nothing and after that only one statement that is count++, so it is increment the value of count.That is why it print the value in Output:1.